# (Julia) .+ operator does not seem to use my custom broadcast function, why?

Tags: matrix, julia, broadcast

I am implementing a custom matrix which only has a single non-zero value, and no matter what operation you do this is the only cell in the matrix which can ever be non-zero. I have called it SVMatrix (Single-Valued matrix). The code I have so far is

```
struct SVMatrix{T} <: Base.AbstractMatrix{T}
    value::T
    index::Tuple{Int,Int}
    size::Tuple{Int,Int}
end

function Base.broadcast(+, A::SVMatrix, B::AbstractArray)
    SVMatrix(A.value+B[A.index...], A.index, A.size) 
end

function Base.getindex(A::SVMatrix{T}, i::Int) where {T}
    if i == A.index[1] + A.index[2]*A.size[1]
        A.value
    else
        0
    end
end


function Base.getindex(A::SVMatrix{T}, i::Vararg{Int,2}) where {T}
    if i == A.index
        return A.value
    else
        0
    end
end

function Base.size(A::SVMatrix)
    A.size
end
```

I then timed the broadcast function together with the .+ operator in the following way

```
function time(n::Int)
    A = SVMatrix(1.0, (3,4), (n, n))
    B = rand(n,n)
    @time broadcast(+, A, B)
    @time A .+ B
end

time(1000)
println()
time(1000)
```

and got the results

```
 0.000000 seconds
 0.008207 seconds (2 allocations: 7.629 MiB, 47.51% gc time)

 0.000000 seconds
 0.008258 seconds (2 allocations: 7.629 MiB)
```

So it seems like .+ does not use my custom broadcast function even though it says [in the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting-1) that

> In fact, f.(args...) is equivalent to broadcast(f, args...), providing a convenient syntax to broadcast any function (dot syntax).

Why do I get these results?

Comment: That documentation section you quoted is geared towards someone who _calls_ broadcast.  It could perhaps hedge more, but note the parentheticals and discussion on fusing around the part you quoted — that's why.  If you want to _extend_ broadcast, you should be looking here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interfaces-broadcasting-1

Comment: That said, I don't think you want to extend broadcast like this. The result of `A .+ B` as you've written them should not be a "single-valued matrix" — it'll be entirely nonzero!

Comment: It wouldn't be non-zero though, it would change its single value by the corresponding value in B. I am not quite sure I am going to use this particular matrix type to much, it is only a proof-of-concept, I have a lot of other matrix types in mind that I would like to implement and make them efficient. For instance a matrix which only has non-zero values in a specific small square and the rest are always zero.

Comment: But thanks for the clear up!

Comment: You are also defining this function in an odd way: `Base.broadcast(+, A::SVMatrix, B::AbstractArray)`. Here, `+` would not refer to the _function_ `Base.+`, but is instead just a variable that can take any value. Try, for example, to define this: `foo(+) = println("Hello, my name is ", +)`, and then call it with `foo("minus")`, to see what I mean. You can use variables and types in function signatures, but not values like you are trying.

Comment: The type signature for dispatching on the function `+` would be, for example, `foo(f::typeof(+)) = ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a great example of where you *shouldn't* extend broadcast.

```
julia> struct SVMatrix{T} <: Base.AbstractMatrix{T}
           value::T
           index::Tuple{Int,Int}
           size::Tuple{Int,Int}
       end

julia> @inline function Base.getindex(A::SVMatrix{T}, i::Vararg{Int,2}) where {T}
           @boundscheck checkbounds(A, i...)
           if i == A.index
               return A.value
           else
               return zero(T)
           end
       end

julia> Base.size(A::SVMatrix) = A.size

julia> SVMatrix(1.0, (1,1), (2, 2)) .+ ones(2, 2)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
```

The result of `.+` should *not* be `[2 0; 0 0]`!  Were we to use your implementation of broadcast (corrected to dispatch on `::typeof(+)` as [DNF noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698562/julia-operator-does-not-seem-to-use-my-custom-broadcast-function-why#comment103694161_58698562)) your array would be surprisingly broken when others used it and expected it to behave like all other `AbstractArray`s.

Now, an operation where you *could* return a smartly re-computed `SVMatrix` is `.*`:

```
julia> SVMatrix(2.5, (1,1), (2, 2)) .* ones(2, 2)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.5  0.0
 0.0  0.0
```

We can do this operation in O(1) space and time, but the default implementation is looping over all values and returning a dense `Array`.  This is where Julia's multiple dispatch shines:

```
julia> Base.broadcasted(::typeof(*), A::SVMatrix, B::AbstractArray) = SVMatrix(A.value*B[A.index...], A.index, A.size)

julia> SVMatrix(2.5, (1,1), (2, 2)) .* ones(2, 2)
2×2 SVMatrix{Float64}:
 2.5  0.0
 0.0  0.0
```

Since this is an O(1) operation and is a *huge win*, we can choose to opt-out of broadcast fusion and immediately re-compute a new `SVMatrix` — even inside a "fused" expression.  You're not done here, though!

- Need to implement error checking for compatible shapes.
- Need to allow for broadcasting of things like `SVMatrix(2.5, (1,1), (2, 2)) .* rand(2)`.
- Ideally, you would implement a [`BroadcastStyle`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#Broadcast-Styles-1) to allow for dispatch on "at least one `SVMatrix` is in the argument list."  You'd then implement `Base.broadcasted(::ArrayStyle{SVMatrix}, ::typeof(*), args...)` which would allow the `SVMatrix` to appear on either side of the `.*`, but this is an advanced topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Do you mind elaborating on how the ```BroadcastStyle``` works? I have read the section in the docs many times now, but it honestly doesn't make much sense to me.
It seems as though custom ```BroadcastStyle``` is simply an empty struct subtyping ```Broadcast.BroadcastStyle```, but I cannot see what that helps? Which functions operate on ```BroadcastStyle``` and what are their purposes?